# Setting same value in Map in ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, dictionary, immutable.js

When we are setting a primitive value, and if the value is same as the existing value, it wont create a new reference.

```js
const Map = Immutable.Map;
const map1 = Map( {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', 2)
console.log(map1.equals(map2))  // gives true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

However, if we set an object, it will always create a new reference

```js
const Map = Immutable.Map;
const map1 = Map( {a: 1, b: {trial: 'value'}, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', {trial: 'value'})
console.log(map1.equals(map2)) // gives false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

How can I avoid that? If the value is exactly same, it should not create a new reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` does not deeply convert values to immutable objects, e.g. your code stores two different objects. If however you wrap you objects with `Map` or with `fromJS` it resolves this issue.

```js
const Map = Immutable.Map;
const map1 = Map( {a: 1, b: Map({trial: 'value'}), c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', Map({trial: 'value'}))
console.log(map1.equals(map2)) // gives false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```